# how to assign a variable to a html code including an if statement in php

Tags: php, string, loops, if-statement, variables

I would like to have a variable $output inside while loop containing some html and a if statement which will give class ".time_active" only to the first while loop result. I'm not able to find a way to embed if statement properly any help would be much appreciated.

```
$count= 0;
while($start_time < $end_time){
   $count++;
   $output = "<label>
              <input type='radio' class='if($count == 1) {echo 'time_active';}' id='id_slot' name='time'>
               <span class='display'>span tag</span>
              </label>";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: if your `$start_time` `<` `$end_time`, you'll enter an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `echo` within the PHP string - create a variable before the string like so:

```
$count= 0;
while($start_time < $end_time){

   $count++;
   $class=$count==1 ? 'time_active' : '';
   
   $output = "<label>
                <input type='radio' class='{$class}' name='time' />
                <span class='display'>span tag</span>
              </label>";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: My guess: you're sending the OP into an infinite loop

Comment: This is nice and clean. I had no idea i could do it this way, learnt something new. Thank you so much.

Comment: @berend - I see what you are saying and that is entirely possible but hopefully shows how to handle the particular issue with the assignment of the class to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
<?php

$count= 0;
while($start_time < $end_time){
 $count++;
 $output = "<label><input type='radio'";
 if($count == 1){
   $output += "class='time_active'";
 }
 $output += "id='id_slot' name='time'><span class='display'>span tag</span></label>";
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: My guess: No, that does not answer the question.

Comment: += is throwing an error "A non-numeric value encountered" so instead of using += i used .= (concatenate) and then it's working how i wanted it to. So, thanks a lot.

Comment: My bad, replace `+=` with `.=`
Also, I'm just assuming this isn't your full code and that you have some condition to end your loop?